# CSS: calculating the x origin to horizontally centre a scaled object

Tags: html, css, transform

Simple scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/s4tjP/1/

```
<style>
   #outer  { width: 200px; height: 100px; outline: solid 1px Red; }
   #inner { width: 220px; height: 120px; oultine: solid 1px Green;
             -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
             -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
   }
</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>      
</div>
```

The problem is how to calculate the x origin for a scaled object in order to centre it horizontally on it's parent object. All dimensions are known.

The fiddle shows the outer box with width 200px, and the inner box with width 220px, scaled 0.75 resulting in 165px.

An x-origin of 50% sets the origin half way along the unscaled object. That's obviously too much. So, should it not be 50% x the scale ratio (in this instance 37.5%) - but that's not right either. In pixels, half the difference between the sizes seemed like a good way to estimate it but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused...what are you trying to do?

Comment: So the inner green box should have the same amount of space either side and appear to be centered within the red box.

Comment: My question is **why** is the inner div larger than the outer...that seems unnecessary. Oh..and why are you using `transform` to start with?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to show the goal. This is just a pared down example to illustrate the problem; I'm using transform because I want to scale all the contents inside.

Comment: Yes...but **WHY**? There should be NO reason to scale objects down from their containers that I can think of.

Comment: basicly you have to use negative margins or translate or relative position. CSS is not meant to do calculation , even that we have calc() for sizing . this would do : transform: scale(0.75) translate(-5%,0%); or margin:-10px 0 0 -10px; would too ... or modifying display to do some css clipping http://jsfiddle.net/s4tjP/10/

Comment: Okay... anyway, there must be an answer. I'm quite close. A 0.5 scaled object in this scenario would be centred if the origin is (0.5 x (200/220)) = 41.25%. - in other words 50% * ratio of big to small. But I can't extend this to generalise about other scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is more a mathematical problem than a programming one, isn't it.

To begin, you have an inner width of 220px inside a div of 200px, aligned left. Your offset is then 10px (half the difference). You need to move the center of the inner div 10px to the left to get it centered.

Then. you are applying a scale of 0.75. That means a delta (or change) of 0.25. To get a delta of 10px (the movement that you need), you have to apply it to 40px of initial length (10px divided by 0.25). If your transform is happening 40px to the left of the center of the inner div, it will center it.

Now, since the center is at 110px from the left edge, this point 40px to the left of the center is 70px to the right of the left edge.

And finally, 70px in a 220px width is 31.81 %.

Try it and you will see

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant, thank you @vals. Since the x-origin can be expressed in pixels, we can simplify thus:

```
x = outer width 
j = inner width 
s = scale 
k = js (scaled width)
d = 1-s (delta)

x-offset = (x-k) / 2d
x-offset = (outer width - (inner width * scale)) / 2 (1 - scale)
```

That's immensely useful (sorry @Paulie_D !)